# How to make bar thinner in R using barplot()?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm struggling to customize my barplot, especially to make it less wide.. Because I only have to plot one bar, I don't know how to make it thinner…

This is my code so far:

```
plot <- barplot(meand, sub = "Mean dprime with SEM",  ylab = "mean d'", ylim = c(0,0.2), axes = T, width = c(0.25, 0.3))
arrows(plot, (meand-sem), plot, y1= (meand+sem), code = 3, angle = 90, xpd = T)
```

Comment: if you do a dput(meand) and you post the output, we will be able to see the data and experiment with it in our computers, that will make it easier to help you

Comment: `meand` is just one value?

Comment: Forget the RStudio plot window, it's just a preview. Better save it as `png`, for one bar try: `png("myPlot.png", height=400, width=200);plot <- barplot(...);arrows(...);dev.off()`. You also may try `pdf`. For two bars use `width=400`, etc.

Comment: Hey guys, I figured it our how to kinda make it look like i want it to look (basically I just did c(meand, 0, 0) and then cut the picture…. not the most elegant way right haha but it does the job. Thank you so much for your help anyways! Really really appreciate it